# Python big file parsing with re

Tags: python, regex, file

How to parse a large file with regular expressions (using the `re` module), without loading the whole file in string (or memory)? Memory mapped files don't help because their content can't be converted to some kind of lazy string. The `re` module only supports string as content argument.

```
#include <boost/format.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/mapped_file.hpp>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    boost::iostreams::mapped_file fl("BigFile.log");
    //boost::regex expr("\\w+>Time Elapsed .*?$", boost::regex::perl);
    boost::regex expr("something usefull");
    boost::match_flag_type flags = boost::match_default;
    boost::iostreams::mapped_file::iterator start, end;
    start = fl.begin();
    end = fl.end();
    boost::match_results<boost::iostreams::mapped_file::iterator> what;
    while(boost::regex_search(start, end, what, expr))
    {
        std::cout<<what[0].str()<<std::endl;
        start = what[0].second;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

To demonstrate my requirements. I wrote a short sample using C++(and boost) the same I want to have in Python.

Comment: Unless you need multiline regex, parse the file line by line.

Comment: Perhaps if you rephrased the question as to what you have, and what you want to achieve, it'd give us a better opportunity to make suggestions - unless you're adamant to a particular approach.

Answer (score 8):

Everything now works ok(Python 3.2.3 has some differences with Python 2.7 in interface). Search patter should be just prefixed with b" to have a working solution(in Python 3.2.3).

```
import re
import mmap
import pprint

def ParseFile(fileName):
    f = open(fileName, "r")
    print("File opened succesfully")
    m = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access = mmap.ACCESS_READ)
    print("File mapped succesfully")
    items = re.finditer(b"\\w+>Time Elapsed .*?\n", m)
    for item in items:
        pprint.pprint(item.group(0))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ParseFile("testre")
```

Comment: This is neat, since it allows usage of multi-line regular expressions.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on what sort of parsing you're doing.

If the parsing you're doing is linewise, you can iterate over the lines of a file with:

```
with open("/some/path") as f:
    for line in f:
        parse(line)
```

otherwise, you'll need to use something like chunking, by reading chunks at a time and parsing them. Obviously this would involve being much more careful in case what you're trying to match overlaps with chunk boundaries.

Comment: Thanks by I'm searching for patterns in stream without checking line boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on Julian's solution, you could achieve chunking (if you want to do multiline regexes) by storing and concatenating consecutive lines, like so:

```
list_prev_lines = []
for i in range(N):
    list_prev_lines.append(f.readline())
for line in f:
    list_prev_lines.pop(0)
    list_prev_lines.append(line)
    parse(string.join(list_prev_lines))
```

This will keep a running list of the previous N lines, the current line included, and then parse the multi-line group as a single string.

Comment: Yes but I don't know how much lines would be needed(in general) and actually this case is just sub case read whole file to memory. Instead I would like to have general solution using memory mapped files(because of the  easy of use and good efficiency).